# Zusammenrückung vs Durchkopplung?

Tags: compound

I'm studying German morphology; is there any difference between *[Zusammenrückung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zusammenr%C3%BCckung)* and *[Durchkopplung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung)*?

They both count as determinative compound, while *Zusammenrückung* can be connected with or without dash character, but *Durchkopplung* must be connected with dash character to combine the words, as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you talk about this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zusammenr%C3%BCckung and this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung ? If yes, please consider expanding your question that non-knowing people like me get links for further explanations (to understand they cannot answer your question ;-)

Comment: Au man, jetzt habe ich erstmal verstanden, dass es gar nicht um den Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *Durchkupplung* und *Zusammenrückung* an sich geht, sondern um die Prozesse, mit denen die beiden Wörter bezeichnet werden. Das wäre nicht passiert, wenn der OP in der auf Englisch gestellten Frage auch englische Termini wie *hyphenation* und *compounding* verwendet hätte.

Comment: I'm sorry for not using the correct terms for english version of Zusammenrückung for compounding and hyphenation for Durchkupplung. I only know the german terms.
Yes, the wikipedia links are correct.

Comment: It's *Durchk**o**pplung*, not *Durchk**u**pplung*

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I'm so sorry about that. I thought it was Durchkupplung, but it was Durchkopplung

Comment: @kuroshiroi: Please include relevant and short quotes from any page you like that explains each concept. because page - okay, wikipedia is less likely - can move or vanish. so the question would loose information if there is only the link left.

Comment: @kuroshiroi: And yes, you had no links, I did it. I just see them as an improvement in clarification what the question is about. (and in rare times the OP also sees things overseen before ;-) Either get rid of them or improve your question any further, it is "your" question.

Answer (score 3):

There are different definitions of ***Zusammenrückung***, but they have in common that they're **morphological** concepts. When used for a special type of compound, the term usually denotes those that combine an interrelated group of words (syntagma) into one single word and thus often feature inflected parts, as in *Tunichtgut*, *Möchtegern* or *(das) Dankeschön*, but also non-nouns like *solcherart*, *allerhand*. You're right that in some cases they can feature hyphens to improve legibility, like *das Aufs-Klo-Müssen* in place of *das Aufsklomüssen*.

***Durchkopplung***, however, is mainly an **orthographical** thing if interrelated nouns (however they might be connected, be it by *Zusammenrückung* or by *Ableitung*) cannot be merged into one compound. For instance, it's *Werner-von-Siemens-Straße* since * *Wernervonsiemensstraße* isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
I do have one question more: I encountered word like _Support-Beitrag_
Is it _Zusammenrückung_ or _Durchkopplung_ ?

Comment: As I tried to explain, it is not *either or*. Grammatically, *Supportbeitrag* is a nominal compound and thus, orthographically, it needs to be written together. As an alternative to writing it together, it is *durchkoppelt*. However, it is not a *Zusammenrückung* because that would be a special kind of compound where a group of (inflected) words is merged (which I would argue is not the case here since two nouns are merged without modification).

Comment: So a) it is an ordinary compound, not a special *Zusammenrückung* compound; b) it can exceptionally be *durchkoppelt* here, because it is not a very common compound, *Support* is a loanword and both elements are full words themselves (not every compound can be *durchkoppelt*)